# run this query from oacle in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can not convert this query from oracle to posgresql. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Select tdcollid, tddate, tdentry, tdlng, tdlat, tdvpid 
From Tracking where Tdcollid = 'jperez'
And Trunc(Tddate) = Trunc(To_Date('14-DEC-16','yyyy-MM-DD')) 
order by Tddate
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `Trunc(To_Date('14-DEC-16','yyyy-MM-DD'))` can be simplified to `To_Date('14-DEC-16','yyyy-MM-DD')`

Comment: What data type is the column `tddate` in your Postgres database?

Comment: BTW `"yyyy-MM-DD"` is not for `"14-DEC-16"`... For this value try something like `"yy-MON-DD"` or `"DD-MON-yy"`...

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
Select tdcollid, tddate, tdentry, tdlng, tdlat, tdvpid
From Tracking
where Tdcollid = 'jperez' And
      ttdate >= '2016-12-14'::date and
      ttdate < '2016-12-14'::date + interval '1 day'
order by Tddate;
```

Note that the date comparisons are arranged so they can use an index (if appropriate).  You can use the same logic as `ttdate::date = '2016-12-14'::date` if this is not a concern.

Comment: Nitpicking: `'2016-12-14'::date + interval '1 day'` returns a `timestamp`. Using `'2016-12-14'::date + 1` would "preserve" the `date` data type

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT tdcollid, tddate, tdentry, tdlng, tdlat, tdvpid
FROM tracking
WHERE tdcollid = 'jperez'
  AND tddate::date = '2016-12-14'::date
ORDER BY tddate
```

If `tddate` is a timestamp, casting it to date with `::date` will do the same as Oracle's `TRUNC(timestamp)`. Also date constants should be preferably in ISO-8601 format.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22051336)